# How to add pull to refresh on angular8

Tags: android, angular

I have an angular web application which is converted into Android App using a capacitor, I would like to add pull to refresh functionality, when I searched on the Internet I haven't found any solution for angular 8, but I have found the solution for Angular Js.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pull-to-refresh

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot    I am using typescript on my project, I am not aware of this scope concept, can you give an example using typescript

Comment: Has anyone found a solution here? I'm also on the lookout.